# C++ SFML - Render at Specific Coordinates

Tags: c++

I wanted to have my own game rendering style, but I want to know how to render a sprite at specific coordinates in SFML. I know you can do things like `sprite.setPositon(20, 56)` but I want to do it more like `window.drawAt(mySprite, 20, 56)`, because that would be a lot easier.

Comment: There is no miracle, you need to create your own function. I created 2 class texture and sprite and then i manage more complex methods from there

Comment: @demonofnight should I use pointers or references for a function?

Comment: In c++ you should use reference as a OO/C++ approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function that takes a window and a sprite by reference.

```
void drawAt(sf::RenderWindow & window, sf::Sprite & mySprite, int x, int y)
{
    // set sprite position, then draw it
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
drawAt(window, mySprite, 20, 56);
```

Which is just as easy as this:

```
window.drawAt(mySprite, 20, 56);
```